# How do I target the id of the individual object in this array-Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react.js useState that I set to false by default. So, what I want to do is to change it to true when an edit button is clicked. It is actually array of comments that I mapped and displayed individually. I would like the user to be able to edit the comment he or she made and clicked the edit button specifically for that comment. Here are my codes:

```
const [updateComment, setUpdateComment] = useState(false)



  <h5 className='users-comment'>Users comments</h5>
            {comments.map((singleComment, _id)=>{
                
                return(
                    <>

                        {updateComment ? 
                         <div className='comment-div' key={_id}>
        
                    <textarea className='comment-wrapper' type='text' placeholder='Share your comment'
                    onChange={(e) => setCommentDescription(e.target.value)}
                 ></textarea>
                    <button className='comment-btn'onClick={handleCommentUpdate}>Update Post</button>
                    </div>
                        :
                         <div className='displayed-comments'>
                            
                            <div className="commentPic">
                                
                                <img className="user-pics" src={PF + singleComment.author.profilePicture} alt="" />
                                  
                            </div>
                            <div className="comment-info">
                                <div className="comment-author-div">
                                    <div className='comment-author-date-info'>
                                        <h4 className="comment-author">{singleComment.author.username}</h4>
                                         <p className="comment-date">{new Date(singleComment.createdAt).toDateString()}
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="comment-edit-delete-div">
                                         <i className="singlePostIcon fas fa-edit" onClick={() => setUpdateComment(true)} ></i>
                                            <i className="singlePostIcon far fa-trash-alt" ></i>

                                    </div>
                                   
                                </div>
                                <p className="comment-content">{singleComment.commentdescription}</p>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    
                        }
                       
                       
                        
                       
                         </>
                )
          
            })}
```

The edit button is this line of code:

```
<i className="singlePostIcon fas fa-edit" onClick={() => setUpdateComment(true)} ></i>
```

But with this current line of codes, once I click on that edit button, it affects all the comments that are on display. I just want it to affect only the comment that I clicked on, so that I can edit that particular comment. Thank you as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to put the state in a single `Comment` component, so every component have a specific state.
2. OR you can set the `_id` of the edited comment in the state. like this:

```
<i
  className="singlePostIcon fas fa-edit"
  onClick={() => setUpdateComment(_id)} // <===
/>
```

and instead of

```
{updateComment ? 
   <div className='comment-div' key={_id}>
   ...
```

do it like that:

```
{updateComment === _id ? 
   <div className='comment-div' key={_id}>
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. So, what will the default state be like? It can't be false, right?

Comment: yes it can.. try it. but null or undefined will be better

Comment: it is working now. I can create another useState to change it back to false when it is on the _id. What do u think about the value of the textbox. I set it to be value={singleComment.commentDescription} and created an onChange on the edit button. The problem is that it fetches the current value of the comment div but I can't change the value. But if I remove the value from the text box, I can write inside the textbox.

Comment: The better way is to create new component for single comment, and there create 2 states: one for ```editMode``` and the other of the ```value```.

Comment: Yea, I thought about that. But what I'm still confused about is how to access that value because the value needs the singleComment to access individual comments in the array.

Comment: Pass to the SingleComment component a function that managing that. based on the id